# php if then else statement syntax error somewhere

Tags: php, syntax, escaping, double-quotes, single-quotes

So I am getting the following parse error when this file loads:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), 
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number 
>   (T_NUM_STRING)

I have tried everything to work out why and I narrowed it down to the

```
href=\"start.php?id=<?php echo $res['id'] ?>\"
```

section of the code. I am sure I left out a ' or " but unsure where as it all makes sense to me. Can anyone with a keener eye see where I am going wrong? Thank you.

My code:

```
<td>

<?php if($res['ndaSent'] == "No") {
echo "<span class=\"buttonTestDisabled\"> Start Test</span>";} 
else {
echo "<a class=\"buttonTest\" href=\"start.php?id=<?php echo $res['id'] ?>\">Start Test</a> ";}
?>

</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    echo "<a class=\"buttonTest\" href=\"start.php?id=<?php echo $res['id'] ?>\">Start Test</a> ";
}
```

Is incorrect, you are closing the PHP code before you are done with the PHP code. And `$res['id']` cannot be in your `echo` like that, you should interpolate the variable correctly in the string. Remove the starting and closing tag inside the `echo` like this:

```
echo "<a class=\"buttonTest\" href=\"start.php?id={$res['id']}\">Start Test</a> ";
```

Please check [this awesome guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050071/php-parse-syntax-errors-and-how-to-solve-them/18092288#18092288) on how to fix these kind of syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

You cant had  snippet in echo use simple string [concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

```
<td>

<?php if($res['ndaSent'] == "No") {
echo "<span class=\"buttonTestDisabled\"> Start Test</span>";} 
else {
echo "<a class=\"buttonTest\" href=\"start.php?id=".$res['id']."\">Start Test</a> ";}
?>

</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
echo "<a class=\"buttonTest\" href=\"start.php?id=" . $res['id'] . " \">Start Test</a> ";}
```